Why do I get two values for the following limit using two different methods with the same identity?
When I evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x+x^2)+\log(1+x^2-x)}{\sec x-\cos x}$$
by using the identity $$\lim_{x \to 0} \log(1+x)=x$$, it simplifies to $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+x^2+x^2-x}{\sec x-\cos x}$$ assuming $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2±x=0$. Therefore the limit evaluates to $2$ as the numerator evaluates to $x^2$. But if I multiply the expressions inside the log together by $\log(a)+\log(b)=\log(ab)$,  I get $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(1+x^2+x^4)}{\sec x-\cos x}$$ which evaluates to $1$. Why does this happen?

the identity $\lim_{x \to 0} log(1+x)=x$ --- This is not an identity. Note that the right-hand side can be equal to $2$ or $-0.037$ or $\frac{3}{17},$ but the left-hand side is a constant that is equal to $0.$ And if you're approaching this by using dominate terms, then you need to deal with the denominator when you deal with the numerator, otherwise how are you dividing numerator and denominator by the term(s) approaching zero most rapidly?

The integral??

Meant limit, EBKAC

This happens because the expansion of the logarithm is not correct, in fact you have:
$$\log(1+x+x^2)=x+x^2-\frac12(x+x^2)^2+o(x^2)=x+\frac12x^2+o(x^2)\\
\log(1-x+x^2)=-x+x^2-\frac12(x^2-x)^2+o(x^2)=-x+\frac12x^2+o(x^2)
$$
Moreover, note that
$$\sec x-\cos x=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos x}= x^2+o(x^2) $$
Hence the limit is:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1+x+x^2)+\log(1-x+x^2)}{\sec x-\cos x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2/2+x^2/2+o(x^2)}{x^2+o(x^2)}=1$$

Another method is to render
$\ln(1+x+x^2)+\ln(1-x+x^2)=\ln[(1+x+x^2)(1-x+x^2)]=\ln(1+x^2+x^4)$
Now, you need only the first-order terms in the Taylor series to get correct coefficients for $x^2$. To wit:
$\ln(1+x^2+x^4)\sim x^2$
$\sec(x)-\cos(x)=[1-\cos^2(x)]/\cos(x)=\sin^2(x)/\cos(x)\sim x^2,$
where in the second equation the denominator $\cos(x)$ can be replaced by a nonzero limit. So the limiting value of the full quotient is that for $x^2/x^2=1$.

We can use Lagrange's mean value theorem(LMVT)
recall that if $x\rightarrow 1$
$$
lnx\sim x-1
$$
so
$$
\flushleft{I=\frac{\ln \left( 1+x^2+x \right) +\ln \left( 1+x^2-x \right)}{\cos ^{-1}x-\cos ^1x}\,\,x\rightarrow 0
\\
=\frac{\ln \left( 1+x^2+x \right) \left( 1+x^2-x \right)}{\left( -1-1 \right) \ln\cos x\cdot \cos ^ux}
\\
=\frac{\ln \left( 1+x^2+x^4 \right)}{-2\left( \cos x-1 \right)}
\\
=\frac{x^2+x^4}{-2\left( 1-\frac{1}{2}x^2-1 \right)}
\\
=\frac{x^2}{x^2}
\\
=1
\\
}
$$
